# DAX and FORMAT function

Tags: date, format, powerbi, concatenation, dax

i have a field for date with date, month and year.In my visualization, I need date to be displayed in (MON-Year) format. 
I switched to data view, created calculated column with

```
Mon-Year = FORMAT('table'[Date],"YYYY-MM")
```

Now it's getting displayed as (YEAR and Month number) but I want to change it as month name. 
After changes in data view, when I close apply, the column is present but there is no data type visible.

[image]

Should I create different calculated fields for year and month separately and then concatenate it?
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want month first, then maybe you should specify it that way.

```
Mon-Year = FORMAT('table'[Date],"MMM-YYYY")
```

This may be useful for you:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/custom-date-and-time-formats-for-the-format-function

Comment: I want month name instead of month number

Comment: Did you even try it or look at the link I provided? `MMM` gives the abbreviated month name and `MMMM` gives the full month name.

Comment: yes, Alexis, its working. Thank you for your response.

Comment: please suggest, if i need to join two tables, then shoull i use calculated column or custom column

Comment: That sounds like a separate question, which means you should make a separate post.